# How to make textarea with readonly=false editable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form and a textarea field in it. I need to make it editable, and I don't know how.

```
<textarea id="note" class="input" type="text" name="note">Suggest changes</textarea>
```

When I inspect elements, its readonly attribute is already false, but it won't let me change anything.

I've tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].readonly = false;
$("#note").prop('readonly', false);
$("#note").removeAttr('readonly');
```

None of those help.

Comment: `disabled` attribute?

Comment: By default, a textarea is editable. So you must have made something that make it uneditable. Please show us what.

Comment: post a fiddle of your code. try using `$('#note').attr('readonly',false);`

Comment: Im pretty sure, somewhere in your code you turned it `disabled`. Because by default a `<textarea>` is editable.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].readonly = false;
```

It should be

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].readOnly = "false";
```

Or also in your case

```
document.getElementById("note").readOnly = "false";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$("#note").attr("readonly", false);
```

Answer (score 3):

I see, the `element.removeAttribute('readonly')` works, but I tried only firefox yet.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it with this:

```
document.getElementById("note").removeAttribute('readonly')
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem really is the use of the wrong case, `readonly` should be written in camel case i.e 'readOnly', so this should work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].readOnly = false;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_readonly.asp